# Repeat a bit of code?

Tags: java

I want to complete a task, which assigns the variable `randomButton` a value. At the end, I want to check the value of `randomButton` If it is something I don't like, I want to re do the task where I assign `randomButton` a value.

I want to do this task:

```
        int i = rng.nextInt(4); //Find random button from between 1-4
        randomButton = buttons.get(i);
        buttonBackground = randomButton.getBackground();
        Log.v(TAG, "In the do");
```

and if

```
buttonBackground.equals(R.drawable.redcircle)
```

I want to try and do the task again. How do I achieve this...?

I have tried:

```
do {
            int i = rng.nextInt(4); //Find random button from between 1-4
            randomButton = buttons.get(i);
            buttonBackground = randomButton.getBackground();
            Log.v(TAG, "In the do");
        }while(buttonBackground.equals(R.drawable.redcircle));
```

But, for some reason, the code in the do part still executes even if buttonBackground equals R.drawable.redcircle. Also, can I make buttonBackground a string so that I can log it?

By the way, `buttons` is an arraylist with different image button objects.  I want to see if the background of that imagebutton (randomButton) is redcircle. If it is, I want to go through the code again. If it isn't, thats great, and I can continue.

Comment: I think there is a confusion in your question. You say that *if buttonBackground.equals(R.drawable.redcircle), you want to try and do the task again*. But then you say that *"for some reason, the code in the do part still executes even if buttonBackground equals R.drawable.redcircle"*. Well, wasn't that exactly what you wanted?

Comment: Please limit your posts to a single question. If you have many questions, please create many question posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, then this is my suggestion...

Create a function that returns a bool value. True if succeeded, false if not. Have that function run itself until it produces true. This is called a recursive function.

Ex in slight psudo-code:

```
bool foo()
{
    bool success = myfunction();
    if not success
        foo();
    return true;
}
```